# Get Azure blob container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get a container if it exists, if not, to create it.

My confusion is because `GetBlobContainersAsync` returns a `BlobContainerItem` and `CreateBlobContainerAsync` returns a `BlobContainerClient`.

When I find the container, how can I get the `BlobContainerClient` from the `BlobContainerItem`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(this.ConnectionString);

BlobContainerItem archiveContainer = null;
await foreach (var container in blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync(prefix: Uploader.ContainerName))
{
    if (String.Compare(container.Name, Uploader.ContainerName,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.Ordinal) == 0)
    {
        archiveContainer = ???
        break;
    }
}

if (archiveContainer == null)
{
    archiveContainer = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(Uploader.ContainerName);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't really have to do all of this.

Simply create an instance of [`BlobContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) using the connection string and container name and then call [`CreateIfNotExistsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.createifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_CreateIfNotExistsAsync_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_PublicAccessType_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobContainerEncryptionScopeOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) on it. This method will create the container if it does not exist.

From the documentation:

> The `CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType, IDictionary<String,String>, BlobContainerEncryptionScopeOptions, CancellationToken)` operation creates a new container under the specified account.
>   **If the container with the same name already exists, it is not changed**.

Something like:

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(this.ConnectionString, Uploader.ContainerName);
await blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

Comment: To use an authorized BlobServiceClient (typically through DI) the same approach can be used by instantiating the BlobContainerClient with `BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");`